# Keeping the mouse on an element when content loads above it

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouse

I have a button that, when clicked, adds or removes content above it.

The problem is that when the content loads it scrolls the page so that the mouse is no longer over the button, and that makes it hard to click it again.

My question is, is there a (jquery) preferred technique for keeping the mouse over that button?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the pixels of the element that is being added you could do

```
var currentPos = $(window).scrollTop();

addElementWithCallback(function() {
    var adjustment = 20;
    $(window).scrollTop(currentPos + adjustment);
});
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but off the top of my head, this is the easiest.